# git: merge downstream local tracked branch into my local upstream master

Tags: git

**Background:**

I'm an upstream integrator for a small project. I pull from three people, into local tracked branches, view the diffs, and rebase them into my master. Then I push my master to some live area.

**Workflow:**

1. I get email that they committed some new code and did git pull w/ my repo.
2. I check in some work on my master. Now it's out of sync with their repo.
3. I checkout into their local tracked branch.
4. `git pull their_branch`
5. checkout my master
6. if no diff between their_branch..master, then I rebase that branch into master. But, in step 2 I checked in some code so there is a diff.

**Problem:**

At step 3, I want to merge their_branch into my master, but they have not git pulled, so my changes are not in the tracked branch yet. Can I just merge the local tracked branch, or will it merge my master changes that are not in the tracked branch yet, into my master? I can always ask then to do git pull, then I do a git pull in local tracked branch. Can someone explain this to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will merge their changes into your current master branch (with your changes), as you stayed on your master branch after they did their `git pull`. The merge will combine your changes with their changes.

Like you said, you could have them `git pull` first, then you perform the merge with their changes.